# Using Terminal in Phpstorm

Tags: php, laravel

I create laravel project with PhpStorm. I'm using "Git Bash Here " as terminal.
[image]

> C:\Users\kadir\www\basit-laravel>php artisan make:controller TestController
> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

When I try to use the contents of terminal in PhpStorm, I get this error:
[image]

By the way I use vagrant and homestead.

Comment: add your php directory to environment variables path

Comment: Thanks, but I don't find this path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use 'php artisan' cmd in Laravel path (Win)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514444/why-cant-i-use-php-artisan-cmd-in-laravel-path-win)

Comment: This way doesn't exit.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common**

There is this path. But there is no continuation. I don't use XAMPP.

Comment: Please never post textual question details as images.  Folks with screen readers and visual disabilities are unfairly impacted by this type of content.  Also search engines do a poor job of reading this content, so your page is less searchable.  Please read [ask] and then }edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Install your php locally (not recomended, because you will run in another problems with vagrant)
2. Access your vagrant instance (maybe `vagrant ssh` in you project folder) and run the `php artisan` commands

Comment: I understood. Thanks for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is something like this as a git bash alternative:
   https://cmder.net/
2. You must show the terminal called git bash or cmder in php storm

Comment: Thanks for the solution ways.